# GWT Classes generator of inherited interface

Tags: java, gwt, interface

I have interface A:

```
public interface A{
     String someMethod();
}
```

And using GWT.create(A.class) I get instant of implementation of this interface.

However if I create interface B();

```
public interface B extends A{
     String someOtherMethod();
}
```

And do GWT.create(B.class) i get implementation of B interface, but without implementations A interface methods.

And get compilation error:

[Error] Line 3: The type B_impl must implement the abstract method A.someMethod()

Additional:
As i find out later, may be it's connected with Annotations.

So i have:

```
public interface annotationHelperClass{
}
```

that has:

```
public final class annotationHelperClassGenerator{
//Some code
}
```

annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String someParam();
}
```

so interface A will be:

```
public interface A extends annotationHelperClass{
         @MyAnnotation(someParam = "Some string")
         String someMethod();
    }
```

interface B:

```
public interface B extends A{
         @MyAnnotation(someParam = "Some another string")
         String someOtherMethod();
    }
```

Comment: GWT.create(B.class) allows you to create an interface???

Comment: No, it allows me to create instant of this interface, but only with methods that declared in B interface.

Comment: May be the reason in Annotations, i use annotations in interface A that help me to generate implements classes, but annotations doesn't inherited to B interface, so GWT can't generate that methods properly!

Comment: Please provide more informations. With the informations you provided, GWT.create(A.class) will not work.

Comment: What generator are you using? Is it a custom one? Yours? Are you asking how to fix it?

Comment: I provide some more information!May be i should to add @inherited, but i am not sure that it works with interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my generator use:

```
for (JMethod method : targetClass.getMethods()) {
    MyAnnotation descriptor = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        JParameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
        //some code
}
```

So changing getMethods() on getInheritableMethods() solved this problem.

Sorry for being not in detail, i was not sure what is important in this case!